# Binding Web Application, Site Collection, Sites and Library data to a Sharepoint 2007 dropdown list in a web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

A. I'd like to know the best way to retrieve the web applications, site collections, sites and libraries of a SharePoint 2007 install (on a farm) and display each of those data in a dropdown list of their own a web part.

B. What type of web part should be used

C. What object model or database/tables do I get those pieces of information from

For example:

> "Web Applications" Dropdownlist1
>
> "Site Collections" Dropdownlist2
>
> "Sites" Dropdownlist3
>
> "Libraries" in a scrollable Textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
            SPWebService service = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>("");
            foreach (SPWebApplication webapp in service.WebApplications)
            {
                foreach (SPSite sitecoll in webapp.Sites)
                {
                    foreach (SPWeb web in sitecoll.AllWebs)
                    {
                        <<Use recursion here to Get sub WebS>>
                        web.Dispose(); 
                    }

                    sitecoll.Dispose();   

                }

            }
```

the above code sample provides code to find listing of all webs in a spfarm you can use the above sample to find all webapplication, sitecollection, webs, use SPListto get all list item from splistcollection available in SPweb.lists

Comment: You don't need a recursion to get the sub Webs since AllWebs already gives you the top Web and all the sub Webs under the Site collection.

Comment: what if all subwebs under site collection also contain webs ?

Comment: I will gladly choose your answer if you give it to me exactly how it is supposed to look in a web part with the dropdown list functionality

Comment: Nevermind. I got it working..I'll choose your answer... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display each type of data in each drop down list in each own Web part. You can make some connected Web parts.

For example:

1- The Web application list Web part

You can get the data from `SPWebService.WebApplications`. The selected Web application should be used as the filter for the Site collection list Web part.

2- The Site collection list Web part.

You can get the data from `SPWebApplication.Sites`. The selected Site should be used as the filter for the Web list Web part. Ensure to dispose the `SPSite` object after using it.

3- Web list Web part.

You can get the data from `SPSite.AllWebs`. Ensure to dispose the `SPWeb` object after using it.